# jQuery plugin getting undefined values

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am learning how to make my own jQuery plugins and I'm running into an issue I am not sure why I am seeing. Here is my plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.clipping = function() {
        console.log("Offset Width: " + this.offsetWidth);
        console.log("Scroll Width: " + this.scrollWidth);

        if(this.offsetWidth > this.scrollWidth) {

        } else {

        }
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Then on document load I have this:

```
$("#tiles").clipping();
```

In the console I get this:

```
Offset Width: undefined
Scroll Width: undefined
```

Why is this happening? Do I need to do something to make sure it is looking at the exact element by ID that I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside you plugin, `this` is a jQuery object. You should use `.prop` to get DOM properties:

```
this.prop('offsetWidth');
this.prop('scrollWidth');
```

A good practice for plugins is to loop the initial jQuery object while returning it to allow chaining. Inside the loop, `this` will be the DOM element.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.clipping = function() {
        return this.each(function(){
            console.log("Offset Width: " + this.offsetWidth);
            console.log("Scroll Width: " + this.scrollWidth);

            if(this.offsetWidth > this.scrollWidth) {

            } else {

            }
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

And your plugin will work with object containing many DOM elements.